# How to fetch an API that has an URL that changes parameters

Tags: reactjs

I have a `MainComponentWrapper` that fetches data through an url.

This url depends on two parameters: `url = "/api/machine/" + resource_group + "/" +  name`

Now i can fetch those values like this:

```
const name = data.map((row)=>{
     return (row.name);
 });

Json = ["Machine1", "Machine2", "Machine3"]"
```

```
const resource_group = data.map((row)=>{
     return (row.resource_group);
 });

Json = ["resource_group1", "resource_group2", "resource_group3"]
```

But when i try to pass the values to the url what i get is this:

`const url = "/api/machine/" + resource_group + "/" +  name`

`const data1 = <MainComponentWrapper url={url}/>`

the url = `/api/machine/resource_group1,resource_group2,resource_group3/Machine1,Machine2,Machine3`

And what i need is to get the values for each parameter like this:

```
/api/machine/resource_group1/Machine1
/api/machine/resource_group2/Machine2
/api/machine/resource_group3/Machine3
```

Fetch Component

```
export default function MainComponentWrapper({ url, children }) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [data, setData] = React.useState()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
      },
    })
      .then(resp => {
        return resp.json()
      })
      .then(fetchedData => {
        setData(fetchedData)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
          window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token")
          window.location.replace("/")
      })
  }, [url])
  if (data === undefined) {
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {React.cloneElement(children, { data: data })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can i achieve this? fetch the data for each different url so i can print it on a list
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where you fetch (or post the whole component)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use two arrays or a hash in order to execute one request for each URL. The following example uses two arrays:

```js
const keywords = ["resource_group1", "resource_group2", "resource_group3"]
const machines = ["Machine1", "Machine2", "Machine3"]"
let url
keywords.forEach((keyword, index) => {
url = "/api/machine/" + keyword + "/" + machines[index]
// your fetch mechanism
})
```

Comment: Thanks, i can get the different urls now, but can you answer me this pls, if i'am using a wrapper like i posted on the question to fetch my data, how can i print the values for each fetch?

Comment: The `url` changes for every iteration, so you'd need to call `fetch` from inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because your `resource_group` and `name` are of type array.
You should do it like this:

```
let url;

for(let i = 0; i < resource_group.length; i++) {
  url = "/api/machine/" + resource_group[i] + "/" +  name[i]
  // do whatever you want to do with that url
}
```

So, generally your issue is that you are setting the whole arrays in url